# ¿Cómo deben escribirse las extensiones de formato de archivo en un texto?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, informática, escritura

He leído en [una pregunta de English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/291025/307023) que según una convención de escritura técnica, las extensiones de formatos de archivo en un texto deben escribirse .pdf o .png (minúscula y con el punto delante).

> Current convention in technical writing is to use lowercase for file name extensions. Both the Apple Style Guide (page 8) and the Microsoft Manual of Style (page 122) request writers use lowercase for file extensions and to include the dot.

¿Esto es aplicable al castellano?

Comment: creo que ya tenemos esta pregunta

Comment: A mí me gusta usar minúsculas en inglés en general, pero mayúsculas si tengo que agregar -s para formar el plural.  (No obstante lo que hayas encontrado en ELU.)  Pero en español no se agrega -s para formar el plural, así que me siento libre a escoger *pdf* si quiero.  Ahora, si viene en el contexto del nombre completo del archivo, p. ej. "borrador.pdf", entonces ahí tiene que ser con minúsculas, a mi aviso. // Interesante pregunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece que sí. Alguien debió de preguntar a la RAE en Twitter si "MP3" se escribía en mayúscula o minúscula. No encuentro el tuit original, pero [la respuesta de la RAE](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/856472915814043648) fue:

> Las siglas, en mayúsculas: «MP3». Las extensiones de archivos, en minúsculas: «mp3».

De aquí se puede inferir que la RAE recomienda escribir las extensiones de archivo en minúscula. Me falta saber si recomiendan el uso del punto antes de la extensión. Les he lanzado una pregunta en Twitter y tras una semana (se lo han pensado) me han respondido [lo siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1019479579541626880) (añado cursivas para mejor lectura):

> Si lo que usted desea reproducir es la extensión, lo indicado es el uso del punto y la minúscula: *Mueve todos los archivos .doc a este directorio.*
>   Si se trata de la sigla del formato, con mayúscula y sin punto: T*e mando el PDF que me pediste.*

Comment: Es que esto del punto dentro de una oración es inaudito para mí, el idioma inglés acepta cosas que en castellano no son válidas.

Comment: @Danielillo bueno, la RAE recoge el uso del punto como signo delimitador en direcciones web y de correo electrónico en su _Ortografía_, tampoco sería descabellado que aceptaran ese uso del punto para las extensiones de archivo. Por cierto, bienvenido al sitio, y buena primera pregunta.

Comment: Yo las extensiones de archivo las escribo en minúsculas e incluyendo el punto delante. Si me refiero al formato lo escribo todo en mayúsculas. Ignoro si hay una norma específica, y aunque la hubiera seguiría escribiéndolo igual.