# What is the gender (and number) of an svg?

Tags: traducción, género, siglas

Quiero traducir la oración en inglés:

> I found an svg.

Pero estoy teniendo problemas con la palabra "svg".

Creo que svg es mejor que gve (**G**ráficos **V**ectoriales **E**scalables) porque [el wikipedio de svg en español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%A1ficos_vectoriales_escalables) no usa gve sino svg.

El problema es que no sé de qué género es.  El wikipedio usa masculino, pero no habla de las imágenes SVG sino del formato SVG. Conozco dos reglas que pueden ayudarme a resolverlo, pero se contradicen.

1. (Palabras extranjeras) Usar el género del tipo de cosa que es.

   *Por ejemplo: Si es un pueblo use masculino porque pueblo es masculino.*
2. (Siglas) Usar el género de la frase completa.

   *Por ejemplo: Es "el RU" porque es "el Reino Unido".*

SVG es una palabra extranjera y una sigla. La regla uno da feminina porque es *una imagen* SVG. Pero porque es "Gráficos Vectoriales Escalables", la regla dos da masculino y *plural?!*

No tengo una intuición de este tipo de cosa en español, así que no sé cual es.

¿Qué género debería usar en esta oración? Y, ¿cómo puedo saberlo en el futuro?

Comment: He editado un poco el texto de tu pregunta, corrigiendo alguna errata y haciéndolo un poco más idiomático. He cambiado "paraula" por "palabra" ya que aunque se entienda y seguramente comparten raíz latina, la primera no está recogida en el DRAE

Comment: Esta pregunta se parece a [¿Cómo deben escribirse las extensiones de formato de archivo en un texto?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26870/1674). Sin embargo, no coincide ninguna etiqueta. Esto es malo.

Answer (score 7):

Debes usar masculino. 
Aunque puede aceptarse «encontré una svg» y se entenderá una imagen, para un hispanohablante será más natural «encontré un svg» y se entenderá archivo de imagen o formato de imagen, tal como dices que está en wikipedia.

Creo que siempre, o habrá pocas excepciones, se utiliza masculino para los nombres de formato o extensión, manteniendo la forma original PDF (nunca FDP), y se entiende formato, extensión, archivo (todos masculinos) y no una traducción de lo que las siglas significan. Muchos saben lo que es un JPEG, pocos que las siglas significan “Joint Photographic Experts Group”.

En cuanto al número siempre singular. 
Suena natural «Encontré varios svg» o «encontré unos svg» pero no hay forma plural de esa palabra.

En manual de gramática de la RAE 2.5.1a y 3.2.3c

Comment: Hoy en día no es extraño escuchar a la gente decir el plural de PDF como "pedefes". ¿Es posible que en un futuro la RAE incorpore esta palabra, como ya ocurrió con cedés (de CD)?

Comment: En realidad lo que usa la gente es el plural de la sigla: pe-de-efes (PDFs). Del mismo modo que hablamos de APIs.

Igualmente, @nakaki, las siglas nativas no se pluralizan en español. Por ejemplo: Sociedad de Responsabilidad Limitada (SRL). No decimos "las SRLs /ese-erre-eles/" como en PDFs, sino "las SRL /ese-erre-ele/". Idem para Sociedad Anónima y varias otras siglas que no provienen del Inglés.

Answer (score 2):

Si se está hablando de una imagen codificada en SVG entonces usar femenino:

```
  la imagen SVG
```

pero si está hablando del formato o la estrucutura en sí misma, es masculino como en:

```
 el formato SVG tiene capacidad de...
```

Comment: Quien pregunta está usando 'SVG' como sustantivo.
En tu caso es correcto lo que afirmás, pero no responde _exactamente_ a la pregunta, dado que hablas de SVG como modificador de imagen/formato.